# Timer in background processing in Xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want the timer to continue when the app is pushed to the Background.
It seems the Timer pauses and resumes when the app is brought back to the forground.

```
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 30000;
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoSaveMethod();
    }
```

Comment: That's not fully possibly by using .net timers. Apps have a very special (OS specific) background behavoir. There are some libraries like shiny background jobs https://allancritchie.net/posts/shinyjobs that allow you to implement it more easy. But you need to understand how backgrounding works on mobile platforms to understand what you can expect. Spoiler: You can't guarantee a execution in background. (read some ios + android docs about it)

Comment: iOS does not allow app to run in background by default. See the document about [ios-backgrounding-techniques](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/).